# Permission denied when creating a storage trigger with a named storage bucket

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

```
Insufficient permissions to (re)configure a trigger (permission denied for bucket images). Please, give owner permissions to the editor role of the bucket and try again.
```

[image]

I am pretty new to firebase. I am trying to implement that if i upload image it resizes it and change the name.

The bucket name in what i want to have resized images is "images"
Why it complains about permissions if i have access to read and write?

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

_

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const gcs = require("@google-cloud/storage")();
const os = require("os");
const path = require("path");
const spawn = require("child-process-promise").spawn;

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
exports.onFileChange = functions.storage
  .bucket("images")
  .object()
  .onFinalize(event => {
    const bucket = event.bucket;
    const contentType = event.contentType;
    const filePath = event.name;
    console.log("File change detected, function execution started");

    if (object.resourceState === "not_exists") {
      console.log("We deleted a file, exit...");
      return;
    }

    if (path.basename(filePath).startsWith("resized-")) {
      console.log("We already renamed that file!");
      return;
    }

    const destBucket = gcs.bucket(bucket);
    const tmpFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), path.basename(filePath));
    const metadata = { contentType: contentType };
    return destBucket
      .file(filePath)
      .download({
        destination: tmpFilePath
      })
      .then(() => {
        return spawn("convert", [
          tmpFilePath,
          "-resize",
          "500x500",
          tmpFilePath
        ]);
      })
      .then(() => {
        return destBucket.upload(tmpFilePath, {
          destination: "resized-" + path.basename(filePath),
          metadata: metadata
        });
      });
  });
```

Comment: Are you sure your bucket name is "images"?  That seems unlikely.  Bucket names are required to be unique across all of Cloud Storage.  How exactly did you create this bucket?

Comment: I uploaded a picture of a bucket name

Comment: I tried to change bucket name to "images/" and it returned 
"Invalid bucket name ${bucket}"
Then i changed back to "images" and it returned 
"Insufficient permissions to (re)configure a trigger (permission denied for bucket images)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're describing is a folder inside a bucket, not a bucket. What you likely want to do instead do `.bucket().object()` in your trigger definition and then, at the top of your function, do something like:

```
// Exit if this is triggered on a file that is not an image.
if (!filePath.startsWith('images/')) {
  console.log('This is not in the images directory.');
  return null;
}
```

Comment: "  .bucket()
  .object("images")"
 I added this and when i upload image in "images" directory, it creates resized image in home directory not in "images" folder. How i can point in to images folder?

Comment: `return destBucket.upload(tmpFilePath, {
          destination: "images/resized-" + path.basename(filePath),
          metadata: metadata
        });`